# Avoid having to press backspace before typing in selectize.js <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a single choice `<select>` element which is enhanced using [`selectize.js`](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/).

The `<select>` element has a pre-selected `<option>` (the current value).

If users want to change this value, they have to

1. click on the drop down control,
2. press **backspace** to clear the current value,
3. start typing their search and
4. select the matching result from the autocomplete suggestions list.

Can we avoid **step 2** (having to press backspace before being able to type)?

Users should be able to click the control and start typing instantly.

Are you aware of a selectize.js plugin, a config parameter or a jQuery based event handler function to achieve that behavior?

Comment: They have a [`onFocus`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#callbacks) event handler and a [`clear`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_items) for the items, I'd imagine that you could call that in the `onFocus` event and it'd work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @George!

Indeed it works like this:

```
$( 'form.myform select' ).selectize( {
    create: false,
    diacritics: false,
    onFocus: function() {     // <-
        this.clear( false );  // <-
    }                         // <-
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this(it store previous value, and restore after focusout):

```
        let value;
        //...
        //When opening dropdown get the value
        onDropdownOpen: function() {
            value = this.getValue();
            this.clear(false)
        },
        //When closing empty dropdown, set the grabbed value
        onBlur: function() {
            if(this.getValue() == '') {
                this.setValue(value);
            }
        },
```